# How to parse my json string in C#(4.0)using Newtonsoft.Json package?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am new to JSON.In my asp.net application i want to parse the json string.So, i have used Newtonsoft.Json package for reading and writing json data.Now, i can able to parse the simple json data.But now i have received some complex json data for parsing.So, i little bit struck on it.

**This is JSON Data:**

```
{
    quizlist: [
     {
            QUIZ: {
                'QPROP': [
                    {
                        'name': 'FB',
                        'intro': '',
                        'timeopen': '1347871440',
                        'timeclose': '1355733840',
                        'timelimit': '0',
                        'noofques': '5',
                        'QUESTION': {
                            'QUEPROP': [
                                {
                                    'questiontext': 'Scienceisbasedont',
                                    'penalty': '0.3333333',
                                    'qtype': 'shortanswer',
                                    'answer': 'cause-and-effect',
                                    'mark'  : '5',
                                    'hint': ''
                                },
                                {
                                    'questiontext': 'otherscientistsevaluateit',
                                    'penalty': '0.3333333',
                                    'qtype': 'shortanswer',
                                    'answer': 'Peerreview',
                                    'mark'  : '5',
                                    'hint': ''
                                },
                                {
                                    'questiontext': 'Watchingavariety',
                                    'penalty': '0.3333333',
                                    'qtype': 'shortanswer',
                                    'answer': 'inductive',
                                    'mark'  : '5',
                                    'hint': ''
                                },
                                {
                                    'questiontext': 'coveriesorideas',
                                    'penalty': '0.3333333',
                                    'qtype': 'shortanswer',
                                    'answer': 'paradigmshift',
                                    'mark'  : '5',
                                    'hint': ''
                                },
                                {
                                    'questiontext': 'proportions',
                                    'penalty': '0.3333333',
                                    'qtype': 'shortanswer',
                                    'answer': 'fixed',
                                    'mark'  : '5',
                                    'hint': ''
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

**This is my C# Code :**

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

            foreach (var data in dynObj.quizlist)
            {
                foreach (var data1 in data.QUIZ.QPROP)
                {
                    Response.Write("Name" + ":" + data1.name + "<br>");
                    Response.Write("Intro" + ":" + data1.intro + "<br>");
                    Response.Write("Timeopen" + ":" + data1.timeopen + "<br>");
                    Response.Write("Timeclose" + ":" + data1.timeclose + "<br>");
                    Response.Write("Timelimit" + ":" + data1.timelimit + "<br>");
                    Response.Write("Noofques" + ":" + data1.noofques + "<br>");
                }
              }
```

I can able to parse until noofques object in QPROP array objects.Now have to parse data.QUIZ.QPROP.QUESTION.QUEPROP array objects also...

But i failed to parse fully...

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
foreach (var data in dynObj.quizlist)
{
    foreach (var data1 in data.QUIZ.QPROP)
    {
        Response.Write("Name" + ":" + data1.name + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Intro" + ":" + data1.intro + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Timeopen" + ":" + data1.timeopen + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Timeclose" + ":" + data1.timeclose + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Timelimit" + ":" + data1.timelimit + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Noofques" + ":" + data1.noofques + "<br>");

        foreach (var queprop in data1.QUESTION.QUEPROP)
        {
            Response.Write("Questiontext" + ":" + queprop.questiontext  + "<br>");
            Response.Write("Mark" + ":" + queprop.mark  + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use this tool to create appropriate c# classes:

http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

and when you will have classes created you can simply convert string to object:

```
    public static T ParseJsonObject<T>(string json) where T : class, new()
    {
        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jobject.ToString());
    }
```

Here that classes: http://ge.tt/2KGtbPT/v/0?c

Just fix namespaces.

Comment: :Thanks.It created some .cs files.How do i use it in my application.I want to store that information into my DB.for example,my json string contains arrays then i want to store it in C# array and then copy to my Database...

Comment: ok, just add that cs files to your project and fix namespaces. Next, when you will have raw json string you can convert it to object by calling SampleResponse1 obj = ParseJsonObject<SampleResponse1>(jsonStr); Note! SamplemResponse1 is root class genereated by that tool, if you clicked Generate without setting another name. Probably you will want to change it

Comment: :then how do i store all the details parsed from json string into C# data structure...

Comment: ParseJsonObject will return c# class to you. So if e.g. root class generated by that tool called RootJson.  RootJson obj =  ParseJsonObject<RootJson >(jsonStr);  next to access all quizez simply use foreach(Quiz quiz in obj.Quizlist ) {//here you can read all properties of current quiz}. Next you can store these properties in database

Comment: :Now i understood...Thanks for your efforts...But now i want to read it from each http request.I have 4 different json data.So, i have to create C# code for those data early and then do your process according to the web request right... tell me am i wrong or right?

Comment: yes, if you have different structure of json strings you need to create classes for those strings and after you will have it you will be able to convert string representation to c# object like described above. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You could create your own class of type Quiz and then deserialize with strong type:

Example:

```
quizresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quiz>(args.Message,
                 new JsonSerializerSettings
                 {
                     Error = delegate(object sender1, ErrorEventArgs args1)
                     {
                         errors.Add(args1.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                         args1.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                     }
                 });
```

And you could also apply a schema validation.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple example of JSON parsing by taking example of google map API. This will return City name of given zip code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string jsonstring;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            jsonstring = client.DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+txtzip.Text.Trim());
            dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

            Response.Write(dynObj.results[0].address_components[1].long_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all good approach will be to convert JSON string to model using this site https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-to-csharp.html

than use your model
try
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.weatherapi.com");
var response = await client.GetAsync($"/v1/current.json?key=(YOUR API KEY)&q={city}&aqi=no");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

```
var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenWeatherResponse>(stringResult);

return Ok(new
{
    City= rawWeather?.location.name,
    Temp = rawWeather?.current.temp_c,
    Wind= rawWeather?.current.wind_kph,
    Date= rawWeather?.current.last_updated,
    Condition= rawWeather?.current.condition.text,
    Conditionico = rawWeather?.current.condition.icon
});
```

}
catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
{
return BadRequest($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
}