# How to access child value in json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to parse a json to access the child value. Below is the sample json,

```
jsondata = {
  "sample_data": "{"o2:{"testname":"o2","department":"chemistry","normalvalue":"l","testmethod":"j","specimen":"g","referelprice":"y","normalprice":"i","discountprice":"o"}}"
}
```

Below is my code

```
var _json = JObject.Parse(jsondata.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(_json["sample_data"]);
```

This code gives me the output

```
{"o2":{"testname":"o2","department":"chemistry","normalvalue":"l","testmethod":"j","specimen":"g","referelprice":"y","normalprice":"i","discountprice":"o"}}
```

Now if i try to get the Child "o2" by using

> Console.WriteLine(_json["sample_data"]["o2"]);

i am getting below error message

```
cannot access child value on newtonsoft.json.linq.jvalue
```

Please help me on how to get the child value. I want the output like

```
{"testname":"o2","department":"chemistry","normalvalue":"l","testmethod":"j","specimen":"g","referelprice":"y","normalprice":"i","discountprice":"o"}
```

How can i achieve this. Please help.

Comment: var _json = JObject.Parse(jsondata.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(_json[sample_data]);

Comment: what about `Console.WriteLine(_json[sample_data]["o2"]);`  ?

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839865/how-to-parse-my-json-string-in-c4-0using-newtonsoft-json-package

Comment: I just added the "" in the code which i missed previously. Please check the code once and let me know. thanks in advance

Comment: @ZivS I still doesn't work. Please suggest different code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in your sample `jsondata` value stored againt `sample_data` is string.

Try this

```
var _json = JObject.Parse(jsondata.ToString());
var sampledataJson = JObject.Parse(_json["sample_data"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(sampledataJson["o2"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using dynamic.

```
dynamic a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJson);
Console.WriteLine(a.sample_data.o2.ToString());
```

Comment: is this part of Newtonsoft json?

Comment: @Reddy JsonConvert is part of Newtonsoft json, dynamic is part of C# language.

Comment: Just add that detail in the answer as well.. Just a link or name of the library, because the OP has not mentioned about using the Newtonsoft library. People here start complaining about it. :)

Comment: @Reddy JObject is part of Newtonsoft library so I don't need to add anything. He already is using it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Console.WriteLine(a.sample_data.o2)?

Comment: @garethb you are right I paste the second json, for some reason they are 2 jsons in the question.

Comment: @mybirthname didnt know that.. JObject was part of it.. I guess your good..