deserialize json object to the right c# object wirth multiple goals
I am curently learning programing and tried a tutorial for a weather-app but the tutorial is a bit out of date. In the API link i would normaly enterthe ctiy name and the weather data would come up first but now only lat and lon are availeble. I know the awnser is probably very obvious but im new and very confused.
This is a example output im suposed to recive:

[
   {
      "name":"City of London",
      "local_names":{
         "es":"City de Londres",
         "ru":"Сити",
         "ur":"لندن شہر",
         "zh":"倫敦市",
         "en":"City of London",
         "pt":"Cidade de Londres",
         "fr":"Cité de Londres",
         "uk":"Лондонське Сіті",
         "he":"הסיטי של לונדון",
         "hi":"सिटी ऑफ़ लंदन",
         "ko":"시티 오브 런던",
         "lt":"Londono Sitis"
      },
      "lat":51.5156177,
      "lon":-0.0919983,
      "country":"GB",
      "state":"England"
   },
]


And this is my code for it:

HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(koordinateUrl).Result;

string response = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Weathermap cordinates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weathermap>(response);


And my class for it

class Weathermap
{
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Lon { get; set; }
}


How do i convert lat and lon to string for further use?
For reference this ist the website i got the api from: OpenWeather
The "read as String" for the http response worked but when i try to somehow Deserialize it to ether string or its own class and more it breaks.  It says "Exception Unhandled" and sends me to the WpfXamlLoader.cs

What do you mean by "isolate lat and lon"?  The rest of the question implies that you're trying to deserialize this data into an object, but there is no code shown which does that nor any information about the error you receive.  Can you clarify?  (If you're not familiar with how to catch and observe exceptions in C#, this is a good time to start looking into try and catch blocks.)

You are getting a json array; you have to deserialize the json string into a List<YOUR_CLASS>()

The following may be of interest: JSONUtils.

Just use a package like Newtonsoft Json and look at these examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839865/how-to-parse-my-json-string-in-c4-0using-newtonsoft-json-package. Happy Coding!

i try to somehow Deserialize it to ether string or its own class and more it breaks. -- then please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing what did not work.  Otherwise, see Deserializing JSON Object Array with Json.net.

You need to use List<Weathermap> as shown in Deserializing JSON Object Array with Json.net.

The simplest option is to use a serialization library, like system.text.json, that help with conversion from to c# objects. The typical behavior of such libraries are that any additional json values are ignored. So if you only want the lat-long values, just define a type containing the values you want.
public class LatLong
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
}

you can then deserialize the json string:
var latLongs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LatLong[]>(myJsonString, new JsonSerializerOptions(){AllowTrailingCommas = true});

Note a use of "AllowTrailingCommas", since that is apparently present in your example. Also note that the examples has a array as the root, so we need to deserialize an array of coordinates.

thanks that worked. Only thing is that using the "AllowTrailingCommas" ends in the error: cannot convert from 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter. Is there a "using" I´m missing and do i even need that whenn its working? And since this is a array, the values are stored like normal right? so i could acces them like example: latlongs[0]?

@Jan There are two major json libraries in .net. Newtonsoft json and system.text.json. Both work in similar ways, but there are some differences. Either can be used, but you probably want to pick one. I.e. either remove the newtonsoft namespace & dependency if you want to use system text json. And yes, values are in a normal array, latlongs[0].lat should give you 51.5...
